# Disassemble library with debug informations

Tags: decompiling

I have an elf shared object (.so) file. What i want to do is to get a c++ file. I know some tools that can do this but result is not perfect. This is because some information are missing in binary files (variables names for example).

But in my case i have a second file which contains debug informations. This is a raw binary file. What does it contain ?

Can this file help me to decompile and see original variables and function names in my output  c++ file ? Thanks

Comment: Even with debug-information you can still not get back the original source. It will still be looking more like high-level macro assembler code than "real" C++ code.

Comment: Okay thanks do you know a tool that can do that ?